# I'm having trouble with com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, jgoodies

When I ran my code on Eclipse, I had this error message

> The import com.jgoodies.form.factories.FormFactory cannot be resolved.

My other import com.jgoodies didn't have any error.

What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

FormFactory has been renamed to FormSpecs in version 1.6 and you are using 1.7.2. See also the [release notes](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/forms/RELEASE-NOTES.txt).